# find a string in text file and create bytes from The rest of the file c#

Tags: c#, find, arrays, text-files, converters

i have a text file contain many line like that:

```
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
text6
```

i want to find "text3" and create byte array from The rest of the file

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove "text3" and then convert the rest to a byte array?

Comment: no, i want to find "text3" and create bytes contain "text4 text5 text6"

Answer (score 0):

Check this code. Here the list Valinbytes is the list that will contain the array of bytes for all values after text3. You can easily convert this to array using the ToArray() method on the list.Feel free to let me know if you need something more from it.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        string[] text =  System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\check.txt").Split(new
         string[] { System.Environment.NewLine },                                                                                       System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
         List<byte[]> Valinbytes = new List<byte[]>();
         int Valtosplit = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < text.Length;i++)
          {
             if (text[i].ToLower().Equals("text3"))
            {
                Valtosplit = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int j = Valtosplit; j < text.Length; j++)
        {
            byte[] byteval = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text[j]);
            Valinbytes.Add(byteval);
        }
    }
```

Comment: check.txt contains the text that you have mentioned in your question

Comment: The first line seems to have a lot of space. Typing here again for your reference                                                                                                                                                  string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\check.txt").Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine },                                                                                System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Comment: i need a byte array (byte[]), not byte[][]!! :(

Comment: I think you can convert byte[][] to a list<byte[]> and than use it to get byte[]. Let me know if you are facing problems